# How to define the basic data types such as Boolean, Interger in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to use Coq to represent the basic data types in OCL such as *Boolean*, *Integer*, *Real* and *String* and the interpretation of basic types, such as I(Integer) = Z, I(Real) = R, I(Boolean) = {true, false}.

I try to construct such type like:

```
Require Import Reals.
Require Import String.

Inductive TB :=
| Integer : option nat -> TB
| Real : option R -> TB
| Boolean : option bool -> TB
| String : option string -> TB.
```

but I cannot write the interpretation.  Is there an easy way to define such data types and interpretation in Coq?

Comment: What's OCL? What do you mean by interpretation?

Comment: @ ejgallego Object Contraint Language, I want to use Coq to formailize the OCL. But I found it difficult in formalization. In other word, I want to construct a set that can be the types of *Integer*, *Boolean*, *Real* and *String*.

Comment: You question is too vague IMHO, a set of `TB` can be built in the standard way, example `{fset TB}`. At some point, you may want to have typed OCB expressions and for that you may want to read about "GADTs". Note: formalizing OCB looks like a full-fledged research project and the required proof engineering will likely be beyond what SO can effectively help.

Comment: Anyways your question can only move forward if you specify what do you mean by "interpretation".

Comment: minor comment: are you sure about using the `option nat` for the Integers? In your definition, `None` would be a valid integer.

Answer (score 1):

A "classical" intepretation in the style of Adam's Chlipala CPDT would be:

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect.

Inductive OT := TB | TI.

Definition OTI (x : OT) : Type :=
  match x with
  | TB => bool
  | TI => nat
  end.

Inductive OE : OT -> Type :=
| EBool    of bool : OE TB
| EInteger of nat  : OE TI.

Definition TBE t (x : OE t) : OTI t :=
  match x with
  | EBool    b => b
  | EInteger i => i
  end.
```

Whether that is useful to you, I am not sure.